# Insert nonbreaking space in Elasctisearch CURL command

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

Trying to get the following to insert a document with the "Admins and Users" _id to work without any errors rising from the _id

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/kibdana-int/dashboard/Admins and Users' -d '{
 "user"  :  "guest",
 "title" :  "Users and Admins" 
}'
```

I tried the following but it put it is

```
  curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/kibdana-int/dashboard/Admins&nbsp;and&nbsp;Users' -d '{
     "user"  :  "guest",
     "title" :  "Users and Admins" 
    }'
```

How can I include a space in the _id?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use spaces for Elasticsearch document ids, you just need to URL encode the ID before using it in curl, in your example you should use:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/kibdana-int/dashboard/Admins+and+Users' -d '{
 "user"  :  "guest",
 "title" :  "Users and Admins" 
}'
```

You can use this small tool to play around with other url encodings:

http://www.url-encode-decode.com/